# NGINX sering 404s despite including server block

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

This seems like an easy problem but its driving me crazy. I already checked the url, permissions, config syntax w/ nginx -t, confirmed about.html is located in root directory but nginx keeps returning 404 when i go to http://localhost:8000/AD/notifications but the default page works

````
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    server {
        location /AD/notifications {
            root /html;
            index about.html;
        }
    }
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;


}```
````

Comment: Nginx is listening on port 80 but you are testing on port 8000, so there are other details missing from your question. Also... Where exactly is `about.html` located? What are the contents of the access log and error log? What default page works? Do you mean `http://localhost:8000/` shows "Welcome to Nginx"?

Comment: Im using a docker that gets port forwarded from 8000 to 80. 

74c84246e305   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 hours ago   Up 8 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   my-nginx

the access log and error logs are empty and yes the "Welcome to Nginx" page works on http://localhost:8000/

the about.html is in the root directory of the docker 

docker run -d -p 8000:80 -v /Users/zgodwin/Desktop/sie/nginx/html:/html -v /Users/zgodwin/Desktop/sie/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --name my-nginx nginx

Comment: Your configuration expects the file to be located at `/html/AD/notifications/about.html` - the pathname is the concatenation of the `root` value with the URI.

Comment: Thankyou very much, i have another issue now it keeps returning a 403 Forbidden even though i changed the user and perms 
drwxr-xr-x 2 nginx root 4096 Oct 17 20:44 notifications

Comment: I feel like nginx is made to be confusing i dont get a 403 when i put an index file in notifications but if i  dont put a file i get 403 instead of a 404....

Comment: Your URI points to the directory. Nginx then tries to index the directory using either the `index` or `autoindex` directives. If that fails the 403 is returned with an error log entry that reads "you do not have permission to index the directory" - which people often misinterpret as a file permissions issue, but is actually a missing index file.

Comment: Thxs again for helping out =)